# AutoFixure, randomly choose from predefined list

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am wondering in AutoFixure, is there a way to randomly choose from the predefined list? For example, when I use `fixture.Create` or `fixture.CreateMany`, it randomly selects an object from the predefined list. I did not find anything similar from [documentation](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet) and searching Stack Overflow, so I am not sure it is even possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ElementsBuilder<T>`:

```
[Fact]
public void Example()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    fixture.Customizations.Add(
        new ElementsBuilder<MyObject>(
            new MyObject("foo"),
            new MyObject("bar"),
            new MyObject("baz")));

    var actual = fixture.Create<MyObject>();

    Assert.Contains(actual.Name, new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" });
}
```

This test passes.

In your actual code base, you should package that modification in an `ICustomization`.