# Customize AutoFixture property generation using constrained random values

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

**Context**

I would like to create a collection of my class, but some of its string property has constrained values. I would like to those values to be still random within the constrained set.

I figured out the customization way, but my the random generation implementation seems to be not using any AutoFixture feature, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel:

```
var random = new Random();
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<MyClass>(b => b
    .With(i => i.MyProperty, random.Next(2) == 0 ? "O" : "C"));

var result = fixture.CreateMany<MyClass>(1000);
```

**Question**

Is there any more efficient way to tell AutoFixture that I would like a random string "O" or "C"?

**Edit**

Meanwhile I realized that the code above does not work at all, so it do not qualify as "backup" plan. (The expression: random.Next(2) == 0 ? "O" : "C" evaluates only once)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/35261711/126014

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Maybe it's me, but I can not figure how either links answers. Both links are customizing a specific object "MyClass" or StreetName generation. In my case the object is "string". Btw I realized, that my example does not work because of the expression "random.Next(2) == 0 ? "O" : "C"" evaluated only once  (I understood why, this is not part of the question). I also understand domain modelling would be better, but I can not rewrite an enterprise application based on my idea of how it should be coded, when my task is to write unit tests.

Comment: OK, I've reopened the post, so I'll leave the link here so that other people can see what I linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47761145/126014

Comment: The easiest way to address this problem might be to introduce a test-specific helper type that you configure with `ElementsBuilder`, and then add an `ISpecimenBuilder` that forwards requests for certain strings to that helper type. See the above links, as well as the following, for some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492820/126014

Comment: OK, all the three read. Although all are clear, they are so overkill for a simple everyday task. I mean in a data model there could be zillion of simple type properties (string, int) where we must pick from a limited set. For all of those properties we must repeatedly introduce helper objects, and write dozens of code lines.. mainly with copy and paste (or develop a helper infrastructure to prevent copy and paste) does not sound practical and productivity enhancer...

Comment: You can also use your code, but add () => for a lambda.  That will allow autofixure to call your code every time it generates that property.

Answer (score 7):

Since [AutoFixture 4.6.0](https://twitter.com/AutoFixture/status/1072235866205118464) you can use callbacks inside the `With` customization function. That allows to constrain the field value, but let it still vary among the created specimens.

Example of source code:

```cs
[Fact]
public void CustomizeMany()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var items = fixture.Build<MyClass>()
        .With(x => x.EvenNumber, (int number) => number * 2)
        .CreateMany(1000)
        .ToArray();

    Assert.All(items, item => Assert.Equal(0, item.EvenNumber % 2));
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int EvenNumber { get; set; }
}
```

You can adjust the sample to meet your particular needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lambda in your with statements will allow Autofixture to call your code each time it creates an object.

```
int totalPending = 0; int numberOfTotalEvents = 100; int numberOfStartingStatus = 10;string targetStatus = "Pending";string negativeTestStatus = "Failed";
var events = fixture. Build<Event>()
.With(specimenFound => specimenFound.Status, () =>
{
    string result = negativeTestStatus;

    if (totalPending < numberOfStartingStatus && Random.Shared.Next(0, 2) == 1)
    {
        result = targetStatus;
        totalPending++;
    }

    return result;
})          
.CreateMany(numberOfTotalEvents)
.ToList();
```